# redirect stdout and stderr while executing docker build > CMD

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I am learning Docker and building a new image.
During the build process, I copy a bash script into the docker (let's call it hello.sh) image and then I execute it. This bash script writes something to the output with `echo`.

I would like to see somehow the output of the `hello.sh` on my console while building the image.

**This is my Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ...
COPY .../hello.sh /u01/oracle/
CMD ["/u01/oracle/hello.sh"]
```

**Docker build:**

```
docker build -t my-helloworld:1.0 .
```

**Output:**

```
Step 6/14 : COPY .../hello.sh /u01/oracle/
 ---> 06e7428586b3
...
Step 14/14 : CMD ["/u01/oracle/hello.sh"]
 ---> Running in fcd495c2e52a
Removing intermediate container fcd495c2e52a
 ---> d21b20deaa26
Successfully built d21b20deaa26
Successfully tagged my-helloworld:1.0
```

**hello.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "I want to see this line on my console while executing docker build..."
```

So I would like to see somehow the output of this internal bash script on my console or at least in a logfile inside the image.

At first, I just started the image with `docker run` and tried to see the output with `docker logs`. There was nothing there to see.

Then I gave up to redirect the container output to my console and tried to log the output into a logfile:

```
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/u01/oracle/hello.sh > hello.log 2>&1"]
```

I tried this as well, hello.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec > hello.log
exec 2>&1
echo "I want to see this line on my console while executing docker build..."
```

No one from the above works.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: That is clear now. So if I want to configure a server inside the container like create an Oracle WebLogic Domain (in case of JEE app server) OR create a new database user in case of if the image contains a database server OR install a new deb package, and I only would like to execute this command once I need to use RUN. But if I want to start the server automatically inside the container when I start the container then I need to use CMD. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) command is not executed during `docker build`. You need to use [RUN](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run). CMD is definition what should be executed, when you are starting container by default (`docker run`).

```
RUN /u01/oracle/hello.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Jan in his answer, `CMD` is executed when you start the container not when you're building the image. If you want to see the output while building the image, you need to use `RUN` instruction in your Dockerfile. But they both serve different purpose.

`RUN` is used to execute a script during the build process. Imagine you want to install something in the final image you're building, you would use `RUN` here.

`CMD` instruction is the purpose for which you built the container (ex - starting an application like `java -jar something.jar`)

Maybe, if you could post the whole Dockerfile and explain a bit what you're trying to achieve, we would be able to help more.